# Rails Spree Kaminari infinite scrolling for the products page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, spree, infinite-scroll, kaminari

I've tried to use this tutorial [Kaminari endless page](https://github.com/fschwahn/endless_page) and also watched Ryan Bates episode [#114 Endless Page (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page-revised) and tried to implement an infinite scrolling functionality to my online store.

I don't know for sure how to apply the products rendering in my index.js.erb file because it's quite different implemented in the Spree. I've also forgot to mention that I'm quite new to the Spree platform.

All I've been doing so far was changing these files:

views/spree/products/index.html

```
<% content_for :sidebar do %>
<div data-hook="homepage_sidebar_navigation">
  <% if "products" == @current_controller && @taxon %>
      <%= render :partial => 'spree/shared/filters' %>
  <% else %>
      <%= render :partial => 'spree/shared/taxonomies' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>


<% if params[:keywords] %>
<div data-hook="search_results">
  <% if @products.empty? %>
      <h6 class="search-results-title"><%= t(:no_products_found) %></h6>
  <% else %>
      <%= render :partial => 'spree/shared/products', :locals => { :products => @products, :taxon => @taxon } %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<% else %>
<div id="home-products">
  <div data-hook="homepage_products">
    <%= render :partial => 'spree/shared/products', :locals => { :products => @products, :taxon => @taxon } %>
  </div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

views/spree/products/index.js.erb

```
$("#home-products").append('<%= j render(:partial => 'spree/shared/products', :locals => { :products => @products, :taxon => @taxon }) %>');
<% if @products.next %>
   $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j paginate(@products) %>');
<% else %>
   $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

Here is the partial views/spree/shared/_products.html.erb

```
<%
  paginated_products = @searcher.retrieve_products if params.key?(:keywords)
  paginated_products ||= products
%>
<% if products.empty? %>
  <%= t(:no_products_found) %>
<% elsif params.key?(:keywords) %>
  <h6 class="search-results-title"><%= t(:search_results, :keywords => h(params[:keywords])) %></h6>
<% end %>

<% if products.any? %>
<ul id="products" class="inline product-listing" data-hook>
  <% reset_cycle('default') %>
  <% products.each do |product| %>
    <% if Spree::Config[:show_zero_stock_products] || product.has_stock? %>
      <li id="product_<%= product.id %>" class="columns three <%= cycle("alpha", "secondary", "", "omega secondary", :name => "classes") %>" data-hook="products_list_item" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
        <div class="product-image">
          <%= link_to small_image(product, :itemprop => "image"), product, :itemprop => 'url' %>
        </div>
        <%= link_to truncate(product.name, :length => 50), product, :class => 'info', :itemprop => "name", :title => product.name %>
        <span class="price selling" itemprop="price"><%= number_to_currency product.price %></span>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <% reset_cycle("classes") %>
</ul>
<% end %>

<% if paginated_products.respond_to?(:num_pages) %>
  <%= paginate paginated_products %>
<% end %>
```

assets/javascripts/store/products.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->

  if $('.pagination').length
    $(window).scroll ->
       url = $('.pagination .next').attr('href')
       if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
         $('.pagination').text("Fetching more products...")
         $.getScript(url)
       $(window).scroll()
```

Here I've changed only the '.next_page' to '.next' according to some comments from the Ryan's episode.

I'm pretty sure the problem is related to the partial, because it's not rendering the products directly, but I don't know how to change this so that it works.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is happening? Are you getting any errors in Ruby or in Javascript, or is it just not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looked like I wasn't rendering the right partials
The content that solved my problem was:

> view/spree/products/index.js.erb

```
<%= render 'spree/shared/products.js.erb' %>
```

I've also created a new js partial for the products because that's where I was actually supposed to make the pagination.

> view/spree/shared/_products.js.erb

```
$('ul#products').append('<%= j render(:partial => 'spree/shared/product', :collection => @products) %>');

<% if @products.current_page < @products.total_pages %>

$('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j paginate @products %>')
BWLD.can_scroll = true

<% else %>

$('.pagination').remove();

<% end %>
```

Comment: hi max I am also stuck in the same issue  tried your way, but still there is no way out. Please help if you can.. [my stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565306/spree-infinite-scroll-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution for anyone still looking for this answer on Solidus.

Add these two files from this repo: https://github.com/gildardoperez/spree_infinite_scroll/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts/store

To your vendor directory As the example below:

`vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend/jquery.infinitescroll.js`
`vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend/spree_infinite_scroll.js`

And make sure to check that you are using the same classes found on the `spree_infinite_scroll.js` file of you app.

Reload your server and load http://localhost:3000/products also make sure to specified the number of products to render per page in your `app/config/initializers/spree.rb`

```
Spree.config do |config|
  config.currency = "USD"
  ....
  config.products_per_page = 10
end
```